# iPhone app and web service

Tags: iphone, service, web

As I am learning to developing in iOS and I would make an iOS app.

I'd like to have a database on a server and the users of the app could access to it. Something like a mini-social network. An app where you can create a user and see/modify the data  of the database.

Well, I may need a web service to get the iPhone communicates with the server but I've been searching and reading info and I don't know exactly how to do it.

A good tutorial or article to read? Some info will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need an host and a connected DB (can be testen local)
[A tutorial how to make a Webservice in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/BeginnerWebService.aspx)
[Or in PHP](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json)

I recogment using JSON as in an output.

[Working with JSON in iOS5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5)

and [Calling the webservice with iOS in a HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188738/asihttprequest-call-restful-web-service)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks you both  I have some experience in PHP/MySQL so im going to starting reading that links :)

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to look at http://restkit.org/

I find use of the Restkit framework very neat and clean when it comes to interacting with Webservices.

here is a nice little tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you "Backendless" .  Backendless is a free server which allows you to dump your data. Im new to iOS Application Development and i have done my MCA Final Project which is iOS Application. For that i needed a server to store my data and to make user registrations.

"Backendless" helped me a lot. Go for it :) www.backendless.com