# Xcode 4 and Databases

Tags: iphone, sql, xcode, database-server

I am new to programing iPhone applications.

I am pretty much done building the interfaces and I built a database using Visual Studio 2008.

Now I want to connect my application to that database using a SQL server as a web service (that acts as an intermediary layer between my application and database). I will reserve a server for the database later.

**My question is:** I have a log in a view where I ask for the username and password, how can I use the information from Xcode and send it to the database to verify it?

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: First of all your question was not clear to me. you should have a web service which can communicate to your database through your xcode by making a connection. There are several mechanism, you can use NSURL.

Comment: Praveen-K  .. 
this is exactly what i want to do . 
i want to send values like name and password from Xcode to my database, through the use of web service - here i used SQL server - to make the communication..  
is there any tutorials you would recommend so i get to have a clearer picture.. 
and thank you for ur help so far :)

Answer (score 1):

From your description I am not sure if I understand, but if you need to have an app and some webservice with data you can check for example this tutorial from Ray Wenderlich:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service

Also, you might find useful this SO question:
[iPhone app and web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620163/iphone-app-and-web-service)

Comment: thank you .. the links u've provided made some concepts clearer .